# Print all the substrings with equal number of zeros and ones, But am not able to

Tags: c++, string, vector, substring

I want to print all the substrings to be printed and everysubstring should have equal number of zeros and ones.I have strated the loop where i points to the index and initially number of zeros and one is equal to 0 and loop runs till both of them becomes equal and i push that in the vector. But My code is not running good . I am given enough time to figure out what could be the error but am not able to find.

Output

```
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Expected Output

```
01 0011 01 01
```

I am not able figure out the error , Please help me with this.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<string> maxSubStr(string s, int n)
{
    vector<string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int ones = 0;
        int zeros = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (j = i; zeros != ones && j<n; j++)
        {
            if (s[j] == '0')
            {
                zeros++;
            }
            else
            {
                ones++;
            }
        }
        if (zeros == ones)
        {
            int size = j - i;
            v.push_back(s.substr(i, size));
        }
        if(j==n){
            break;
        }
        i = j ;
    }
    return v;
}
int main()
{
    string str = "0100110101";
    int n = str.length();
    vector<string> v;
    v = maxSubStr(str, n);
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++, not C

Comment: The logic of your algorithm is difficult to follow. I guess you know that the second argument (`j` in your code) of `std::string::substr` corresponds to the length of the substring. In the loop, you have `j = i-1`, immediately followed by `j ++`. Looks strange, and at least too much complicated.

Comment: Can the substrings overlap? If yes you forgot `0110`, `010011` ,  `01001101`, `0100110101` and several `10`. If no, should it prefer longer substrings or shorter? The whole input fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of little mistakes in your code. You should learn to use a debugger to step through it, the errors would become evident.

In the loop over `i` it is useless to set the value of `j` just before setting in again in the loop over `j`.Then, the loop should be limited by `j<n` to prevent an access past end of string. Next, you do not want to test `s[i]` but `s[j]`. Finally, the test `zeros == ones` should be in the `j` loop and should set `i` to the next position, that is `j + 1`. Code could become:

```
vector<string> maxSubStr(string s)
{
    vector<string> v;
    int n = s.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int ones = 0;
        int zeros = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (s[j] == '0')
            {
                zeros++;
            }
            else
            {
                ones++;
            }
            if (zeros == ones)
            {
                v.push_back(s.substr(i, j + 1 - i));
                i = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: But when I am writing the condition "j<n && zeros != ones" in the j loop and writing the if statement after the for loop of j and removing the break statement. It should mean the same what who have written  But why Its not giving the correct answer?

Comment: @AnshuJoshi Because you tested `s[i]` instead of testing `s[j]`...

Comment: No, I am talking about modifying Your code only  ` vector<string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int ones = 0;
        int zeros = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (j = i; j < n && zeros != ones; j++)
        {
            if (s[j] == '0')
            {
                zeros++;
            }
            else
            {
                ones++;
            }
        }
        if (zeros == ones)
        {
            j=j-1;
            v.push_back(s.substr(i, j + 1 - i));
            // break;
        }
        i = j;
    }
    return v;`